# How to pass argument to a component through router

Tags: angular6

I have a button and on clicking the button, I want to show a new component. While invoking the component, I want to also pass an argument

Eg. `UserDetailComponent` should be invoked and should be passed an `id`. First `UserDetailComponent` should fetch user's information using the `id` from the database and then become visible.

I created the UserDetailComponent as follows:

```
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  id:number //TODOM change to UUID
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("will query db here")
  }
}
```

and create an entry in Routes as follows:

```
{
    path:'user-details/:id',
    component:UserDetailsComponent
}
```

But I don't know how to invoke this component from the button. I have written the following HTML but I get the `error DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ',' is not a valid attribute name`

`<td> <button  [routerLink]="[userDetailRouterLink,1]", id="show-more-button" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Show more</button></td>`

`userDetailRouterLink` is defined in the `.ts` file as `userDetailRouterLink = '/user-details'`

Comment: Could you provide the HTML please?

Comment: oops! updated now

Comment: Haven't you forgotten a " ?

Comment: updated. Was being lazy and just copied a snippet

Comment: Well, you have an "," after routerLink attribute value, it is the cause I think.

Comment: and you are right my friend! many thanks. Happy to accept your answer if you could change your comment to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an typo here:

```
<td> <button  [routerLink]="[userDetailRouterLink,1]", id="show-more-button" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Show more</button></td>
                                                     ^
```

Angular seemingly interprets it as a new attribute (probably some implementation quirk) and as it uses the AOT compilation technique you get the JavaScript error (as the angular template is internally compiled to JavaScript-based DOM manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look on the sample example: If you want to send a ID from list of users component to user details component and fetch user details based on the ID received.

List of user component: list-users.component.ts

```
<button class="btn btn-success" [routerLink]="['/user-details', user.id]">
```

You must have a dynamic route for user-details based on the ID received.

```
{ path: 'user-details/:id', component: UserDetailsComponent }
```

In user-details.component.ts, you should the receive the ID from activated routes, like below

```
// Import ActivateRoute
import {ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
.........
id: any;

constructor (private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,) {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.id = params['id']);

    // After receiving the ID, you can make a call to fetch the user data from database.
    this.getUserDetails(this.id);
  }
```